# How to view web video in media player instead of browser?

Tags: video

Playing media inside the browser is terrible. Until recently when I found a video I wanted to watch on a web page, I would send it to the app Downloader by Mirmay, because it would allow me to play it in whatever media player I like (MX, VLC, whatever). Following a recent update, Downloader now forces you to use its built-in, terrible media player.

How to get web video into a decent media player?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the link of the media file you want to stream, and then open VLC player app, go to More -> New stream below Streams heading, and paste the URL there. It should start streaming directly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon your browser, if you can click on the video itself or click on the browser's menu to share, and on having an APP that will load your browser's 'share menu' (as part of it's install routine) with the open command.

I have a few video players on my phone but most don't automatically fixup the 'share menu', and I've not felt the need to dig around and add the feature manually.

Using the [YouTube APP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube&hl=en) or the [Firefox browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&hl=en) I can click to share and because I have installed [TubeMate](http://www.tubemate.net/) (to download or play) and [BS Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bsplayer.bspandroid.free&hl=en) (stream, or play downloaded video) I can share to them and watch the video that way.

Firefox is usually capable of playing the videos 'well enough' (my phone is a few years old) and TubeMate usually can download from anywhere (and is updated frequently). There was only a week when Vimeo made some changes that TubeMate was finicky, other than that everything has worked flawlessly for years.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox for Android Beta (maybe some other browsers too? - not sure):

1. Click the video link.
2. Browser will open it in its internal player.
3. Press the green Android icon on the right of the address bar (at the
   top).
4. Voila, Android will ask you what app you want to open it with.

Answer (score 0):

Just download it with your *Downloader* and then use a *File Explorer* and search for that file.
It should be anywhere inside either:

- Your usual `Movies` folder (very unlikely, though) or `Downloads'  folder (also unlikely, but possible)
- A unique, created folder by the app itself (many downloaders do that)
- The "external data" folder (`Android/data/<package name of the app>`) on your internal storage
- A configured folder (some *Downloader* apps allow user preferences).

First look inside the settings, then try to find it on your phone's storage.
After that, just tap it and Android will ask you which app you'd like to open it with.

Comment: Sure, that works, but it's not really the solution that I'm looking for. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, export those files from the APP itself (from your phone).
Then, plug your phone to your PC and you'll see a folder "downloadmanager" and click it. After that, you'll see files with no extension and the names would be in number. Click it, add the extension to mp4 (for videos) and mp3 (for music). And Voila! You can now view the files!